# Errors while installing Office 365

Tags: 18.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I'm trying to install Office 365 with Wine on Ubuntu 18.04 from the installer I downloaded with my account on Microsoft's website. Whenever I try opening the setup with Wine, I keep getting the same error (0-2031 (17006)), which asks me to check my Internet connection and hard disk (both are working fine).

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/hhvx17/office_365_is_working_again_on_wine/fwd7bhu/), and I have added the registry keys it talks about with the "wine regedit" command, however I don't know if it is running the installer in 32 bit mode (I've created the prefix folder with "WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot").

What do I have to do?

[here is what I see when I run the setup through the console](https://pastebin.com/fEkT6bpC)

I have managed to start the installation by installing winbind, however it gets stuck at 0% and gives me an error. When I use playonlinux and set "Windows 10" in the wine configuration, the installation proceeds until 45%, when I get the 30117-47 (126) error, which then brings me to the 0-2301 (17004) error. Also, I've noticed some missing characters in the setup's font.How can I fix these problems?